# C# Insert MDB Database Get Last Insert ID

Tags: c#, database, ms-access, odbc

How do I get the Last Insert ID(the auto increment number of table) when using C# System.Data.Odbc insert data ?

Please help. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try below code:-

```
SELECT @@IDENTITY AS ID
```